# Spawn multiprocessing.Process under different python executable with own path

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, conda

I have two versions of Python (these are actually two conda environments)

```
/path/to/bin-1/python
/path/to/bin-2/python
```

From one version of python I want to launch a function that runs in the other version using something like the `multiprocessing.Process` object. It turns out that this is doable using the `set_executable` method:

```
ctx = multiprocess.get_context('spawn')
ctx.set_executable('/path/to/bin-2/python')
```

And indeed we can see that this does in fact launch using that executable:

```
def f(q):
    import sys
    q.put(sys.executable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
    ctx.set_executable('/path/to/bin-2/python')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    proc = ctx.Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    print(q.get())

$ python foo.py
/path/to/bin-2/python
```

#### However Path is Wrong

However when I do the same thing with `sys.path` rather than `sys.executable` I find that the sys.path for the hosting python process is printed out instead, rather than the sys.path I would find from running `/path/to/bin-2/python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` directly.

I'm used to this sort of thing if I use fork.  I would have expected `'spawn'` to act the same as though I had entered the python interpreter from the shell.

#### Question

Is it possible to use the multiprocessing library to run functions and use Queues from another Python executable with the environment that it would have had had I started it from the shell?

More broadly, how does sys.path get populated and what is different between using multiprocessing in this way and launching the interpreter directly?

Comment: This looks intentional: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L218

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem.  My system wide Python executable is at `/path/to/bin-1/python`, and I created a virtual environment using `virtualenv` containing another Python executable at `/path/to/bin-2/python`.  To set up the right path / environment for the spawned process needed for `/path/to/bin-2/python`, I ended up copying the code from `activate_this.py` in the `virtualenv` folder to `f(q)`.

```
def f(q):
    import sys, os

    def active_virtualenv(exec_path):
        """
        copy virtualenv's activate_this.py
        exec_path: the python.exe path from sys.executable
        """
        # set env. var. PATH
        old_os_path = os.environ.get('PATH', '')
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(exec_path)) + os.pathsep + old_os_path
        base = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(exec_path)))
        # site-pachages path
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'Lib', 'site-packages')
        else:
            site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')
        # modify sys.path
        prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
        import site
        site.addsitedir(site_packages)
        sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
        sys.prefix = base
        # Move the added items to the front of the path:
        new_sys_path = []
        for item in list(sys.path):
            if item not in prev_sys_path:
                new_sys_path.append(item)
                sys.path.remove(item)
        sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
        return None

    active_virtualenv(sys.executable)
    q.put(sys.executable)
    # check some unique package in this env.
    import special_package
    print "package version: {}".format(special_package.__version__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    multiprocessing.set_executable('/path/to/bin-2/python')
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
    print(q.get())
```

stdouts:

```
$ python foo.py
/path/to/bin-2/python
package version: unique_version_only_in_virtualenv
```

One thing I'm not so certain is `sys` and `os` are `import`ed before `active_virtualenv()`, which means they are from system wide Python env.  But other packages I need in `f(q)` are from virtual env.  Maybe it's worth re-`import` them after switching env.