# a Python script in 32 bit invoking multiprocessing running in 64 bit virtualenv

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to run a Python script in 32 bit system wide to generate / collect data through a third-party application.  But I want to process the data using GPU via `numba`, so it has to be run in 64 bit Python environment.

I have set up a 64 bit Python `virtualenv`, and testes some simple `numba` code that ran fine in there.  So how shall I write the code in the parent process that will invoke a child process (`multiprocessing` or `subprocess` I assume) that will switch to 64 bit `virtualenv` and does calculation using numba?  More specifically:

1. shall I use `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` to implement the parent (32 bit Python) and child process (64 bit Python) mechanism?
2. how shall I pass large amount of data between the parent and child processes?

possible code sample:

```
def func_32():
    # data collection
    # using 3rd party API
    return data

def func_64(data, output):
    # switch to 64 bit virtual env
    # using virtualenvwrapper-win
    os.system('workon env64bit')
    # numba data process
    # results stored in output
    return None

def main():
    data = func_32()
    # I think I only need one process since it will be in GPU not CPU
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func_64, args=(data, output))
    p.start()
    return output
```

anything I'm missing in the sample code?

Comment: Generally speaking, a 32-bit Python process could launch a 64-bit Python process by explicitly passing the path to the 64-bit Python interpreter executable to `subprocess()` (and passing the name of script file to run as an argument). I don't think `multiprocessing.Process` would work in such a mixed environment since there's no way to specify an interpreter path to it. I don't know how using `virtualenv` would affect things, but it seems like it might work. You can get the path to the 64-bit interpreter from `sys.executable` (when running with that version).

Comment: @martineau I have tried `subprocess()` but had hard time finding a good way to pass data from `func_32()` to `func_64()`.  Seems like data have to go through `stdin` and `stdout`.  I ended up using `multiprocessing`, after I found there is a `multiprocessing.set_executable(r"C:\Python64\Python.exe")`

Comment: Perhaps you can used named pipes as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/355230) to a question about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this question [Spawn multiprocessing.Process under different python executable with own path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39372708/6311906), and found my answer with a little twist given my Python version (2.7.5 32-bit, 2.7.15 64-bit).

```
def func_32():
    # data collection
    # using 3rd party API
    return data

def func_64(data, output):
    # switch to 64 bit Python
    # not directly calling virtualenv
    # to switch env
    import sys
    print sys.executable
    # will print  C:\Python64\Python.exe
    # numba data process
    # results stored in output
    return None

def main():
    data = func_32()
    multiprocessing.set_executable(r'C:\Python64\python.exe')
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func_64, args=(data, output))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    return output
```

But in order to use the 64-bit Python packages in that virtual environment, I ended up copying the code mostly from `activate_this.py` (residing in the virtualenv folder), to change the Python search path etc.  See my answer in [Spawn multiprocessing.Process under different python executable with own path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39372708/6311906).

I think to me using `multiprocessing` gives me more convenient way of passing data between parent and child processes, especially large amount of data.